# Retrieve products properties of specified date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I'm reading a file that is looking like that with a lot of strings

```
PrId    Name  Quantity  Price   Date
  3     Milk    2        100   23-08-15
```

I have a button - btnDat_Click. When i click it retrieves all the dates in a listbox named listDate. I create a button named btnDataToTb_Click, i need to select the date and when i click the button it gonna show properties(Id, Name,Quantity) of all products of that date.

```
  PrId    Name  Quantity  Price
   3     Milk    2         100
```

That's the whole code

```
char[] cc = new char[500]; int i, nr;
string[] lines = new string[250];

public void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string FileName = textBox1.Text;
        FileStream r_stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reads_string_from_r_stream = new StreamReader(r_stream);

        i = 0;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        for (; ; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = reads_string_from_r_stream.ReadLine();
            lines[i] = textBox1.Text;
            listBox1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
            listBox2.Items.Add(lines[i]);

            if (reads_string_from_r_stream.EndOfStream.Equals(true)) goto nn;       
        }
nn:
        textBox2.Text = reads_string_from_r_stream.EndOfStream.ToString();
        r_stream.Close();

        nr = listBox1.Items.Count;
        textBox6.Text = nr.ToString();
}

private void SelectPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFile1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
    if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    textBox1.Text = openFile1.FileName;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt16(textBox6.Text);
    ListB.Items.Clear();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ListB.Items.Add(lines[i]);
    }
}

private void btnDat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt16(textBox6.Text);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(! listDate.Items.Contains(lines[i].Split('\t')[lines[i].Split('\t').Length - 1]))
        {
            listDate.Items.Add(lines[i].Split('\t')[lines[i].Split('\t').Length - 1]);
        }
    }
    listData.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}

private void btnDataToTb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listData.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        string data = listData.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string[] date = data.Split('-');
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(date[0]);
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(date[1]);
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(date[2]);

        DateTime a = new DateTime(year, month, day); 


        for (i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime data2 = DateTime.Parse(lines[i].Split('\t')[lines[i].Split('\t').Length - 1]);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(a, data2);
            if(result == 0)
            listBox3.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", lines[i].Split('\t')[0], lines[i].Split('\t')[1], lines[i].Split('\t')[2], lines[i].Split('\t')[3]));
        }




    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a date");
    }




}
```

Comment: You really should start to learn how to use classes, generic collection of objects and some more 'advanced' features of the language like while and foreach loops. Forget to say that GOTO is.... how to say it... evil?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're approaching this problem wrong. Instead of reading the data, storing them in a list box, then reading and parsing them again when you need to, which is really complicated, you should rather do this:

- Create a new class (e.g. `Item`) that has properties for the product id, name, quantity, price, and date.
- When reading the data, parse the lines immediately and create a new instance of said class for each line. Store these in a `List<Item>`.

  - When working with FileStream, StreamReader etc (anything that implements `IDisposable`/has a `Dispose()` method) you should use them in a `using` block (like `using (StreamReader sr = …) { /* work with sr here */ }`); this will automatically free the object after use.
- For making data visible to the GUI, you can either use data binding, or fill the listbox by hand and get the selected item with SelectedIndex.
- Use Linq for querying data. To select all items on a specific date you can use `var onThisDate = itemList.Where(item => item.Date == selectedDate)`. Linq has many more functions for selecting, filtering and projecting data.